# There is no mysqld under the /etc/init.d after I installed the Mysql use yum

Tags: centos, yum, mysql

I use the below order:

```
[root@localhost /]# yum install -y mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
```

to install  `mysql`.

After installed I want to start mysql by:

```
[root@localhost /]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
-bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: there is no file or directory
```

But you see, I can not start it in this way.

So, I use:

```
find / -name mysqld
```

to find mysqld, I get:

```
[root@localhost /]# find / -name mysqld 
/usr/libexec/mysqld
```

So, I use the:

```
/usr/libexec/mysqld start
```

to start mysql, but get the error:

```
[root@localhost /]# /usr/libexec/mysqld start   
2017-05-19 14:28:17 139762539387072 [Warning] option 'open_files_limit': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295  
2017-05-19 14:28:17 139762539387072 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.20-MariaDB) starting as process 82223 ...  
2017-05-19 14:28:17 139762539387072 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 5035)  
2017-05-19 14:28:17 139762539387072 [ERROR] WSREP: rsync SST method requires wsrep_cluster_address to be configured on startup.
```

And get stuck here.

Someone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Which version of CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS 7 you would use the following command.

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

And if you want mysqld to start automatically on boot you could do

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mysqld
```

Edit: Are you sure that you installed MySQL and you are not trying to install MariaDB instead? MariaDB is the default database engine for CentOS I believe. You can check that it actually got installed with

```
$ rpm -q mysqld
```

Else, I would recommend following the instructions [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mariadb/how-to-install-mariadb-on-centos-7)

Comment: Thank you , I install the `yum install -y mysql mysql-server mysql-devel`, actually is install the mariaDB, alright?